# Assigning static IP address on shared connection in NetworkManager

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, dnsmasq

I am using an old laptop as a wireless bridge to connect three workstations to the Internet. I have Scientific Linux 6.6 installed on the laptop and share it's eth0 device to the workstations using NetworkManager.

I am wondering if there is an elegant way to ensure that NetworkManager assigns static IP address to each workstation based on its MAC address?

My understanding is that the NetworkManager uses dnsmasq as a dhcp server. I've played with `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` but without any success. NetworkManager seems to use some other configuration file when starting dnsmasq.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu, in which static IP can be configured via `/etc/network/interfaces`

Scientific Linux seems to be derived from RedHat, which uses `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` config file instead.

Here's an example of my static IP via `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

For reference, you may checkout this link:
http://blog.shineservers.com/linux-static-ip-address-configuration/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is not what I was looking for. I am trying to assign static IP addresses to three workstations based on their MAC addresses, not to assign a static address to the eth0 device on the laptop. And I would like to achieve that using NetworkManager. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Gentoo.
I use `NetworkManager`, `dnsmasq` and `dhclient` with `systemd`. In my case, I have a PC with dual LAN, one connected to the Internet router and the other to a media player. I want assign a fixed IP to media player and it allows access to Internet through the other LAN. I've gotten the player access to the Internet but not assign a fixed IP.

**/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**:

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile
dns=dnsmasq
no-auto-default=*
```

---

**/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VTEN** (*shared connection / link enp7s0*):

```
[connection]
id=VTEN
uuid=1a887e17-8d8b-460f-8cda-8ca22e5b2f28
type=ethernet
permissions=
secondaries=

[ethernet]
mac-address=1C:6F:65:35:4E:24
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
dns-search=
may-fail=false
method=shared

[ipv6]
dns-search=
method=ignore
```

---

**/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Internet** (*Internet / link enp8s0*)

```
[connection]
id=enp8s0 (Internet)
uuid=39559adb-4564-423a-805e-d12229f22845
type=ethernet
autoconnect=true
permissions=
secondaries=

[ethernet]
mac-address=1C:6F:65:35:4E:34
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
dns-search=
method=ignore
```

To activate dnsmasq as dhcp server I have added this file with the MAC of media player and the IP that I want to assign it.
**/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/servidor-dhcp**:

```
interface=enp7s0
dhcp-range=192.168.2.2,192.168.2.50
dhcp-host=00:06:DC:89:74:36,192.168.2.2
```

To assign a fixed IP to LAN connected to media player I have set
**/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf**:

```
alias {
  interface "enp7s0";
  fixed-address 192.168.2.1;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
}
```

When I started the `NetworkManager` on `systemd` it seems all works:

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib64/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mar 2015-12-08 01:51:15 CET; 59s ago
 Main PID: 25570 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─25570 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           ├─25579 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/libexec/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-enp8s0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-3382e7d4-c7a1-41a1-9b12-a7fa20bb3aa4-enp8s0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-enp8s0.conf enp8s0
           └─26336 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.0.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=400 --proxy-dnssec --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d

dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --destination 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0 --out-interface enp7s0 --match state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT
dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --source 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0 --in-interface enp7s0 --jump ACCEPT
dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --in-interface enp7s0 --out-interface enp7s0 --jump ACCEPT
dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --out-interface enp7s0 --jump REJECT
dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --in-interface enp7s0 --jump REJECT
dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface enp7s0 --protocol udp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT
dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface enp7s0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT
dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface enp7s0 --protocol udp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
dic 08 01:51:21 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface enp7s0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
dic 08 01:51:26 localhost NetworkManager[25570]: <info>  startup complete
```

But:

```
$ ip a                           
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
.....
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:6f:65:35:4e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global enp7s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1e6f:65ff:fe35:4e24/64 scope link tentative
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:6f:65:35:4e:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp8s0
       valid_lft 86401sec preferred_lft 86401sec
    inet6 fe80::1e6f:65ff:fe35:4e34/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The enp7s0 link and mediaplayer have a ¿random? IP ¿assigned by NetworkManager?. Neither dnsmasq (*dhcp*) nor dhclient (*with enp7s0*) do their job.

Comment: Will this work with the GUI tools? Like, if manage connections with GUI tools, will it keep using dnsmasq and reflect any setting done in the GUI in dsnmasq configuration and vice versa? … I don’t think so, since dnsmasq config has root-only permissions and NM GUI tools don’t require root.